# How send and recived mqtt message in same script

Tags: python, mqtt

Hi can someone help me?
I´m trying to send every 2 minutes a mqtt message but I also need to receive messages at any time.

The message every 2 minutes is the state message to know that the server is running and i need to receive messages to execute the shutdown commands.

I try this but this only send  one message...

```
import time
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy

broker = '192.168.15.210'
port = 1883
topic = "LV-Automation/Server"
topicState = "LV-Automation/Server/State"
client_id = 'ServerPower'

msgState = f"ON"

lastms = 10

def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.username_pw_set("user", "password")
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client


def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")
        message = msg.payload.decode()
        if message == "OFF":
            client.publish(topicState, "OFF")
            client = SSHClient()
            client.load_system_host_keys()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            client.connect('192.168.15.220', username= 'root', password= 'Caro1992')
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('powerdown')


    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.on_message = on_message

    global lastms
    nowms = round(time.time() * 1000)
    print("Last Value: " , type(lastms))
    print ("New Value: " , type(nowms))
    if (nowms - lastms > 120000):
        lastms = round(time.time() * 1000)
        publish(client)

def publish(client):
    #msg_count = 0
    msg0 = f"ENCENDIDO"
    result = client.publish(topic, msg0)
    result = client.publish(topicState, msgState)
    status = result[0]
    if status == 0:
        print(f"Send `{msg0}` to topic `{topic}`")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to send message to topic {topic}")

def firstms():
    global lastms
    lastms = round(time.time() * 1000)
    return lastms

def run():
    firstms()
    client = connect_mqtt()
    publish(client)
    subscribe(client)
    client.loop_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subscribe` function will only run once; so your code that checks the time (e.g. `if (nowms - lastms > 120000):`) only runs once. If you moved this up into the callback the code might work:

```py
def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")
        message = msg.payload.decode()        

        global lastms
        nowms = round(time.time() * 1000)
        print("Last Value: " , type(lastms))
        print ("New Value: " , type(nowms))
        if (nowms - lastms > 120000):
            lastms = round(time.time() * 1000)
            publish(client)

        if message == "OFF":
            client.publish(topicState, "OFF")
            sshClient = SSHClient()
            sshClient.load_system_host_keys()
            sshClient.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            sshClient.connect('192.168.15.220', username= 'root', password= 'Caro1992')
            stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command('powerdown')


    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.on_message = on_message
```

However there are a number of issues with this:

- The value of `msgState` is never changed
- The publish only runs when a message is received (which may, or may not, be OK in your use-case).
- Calling `publish` from a callback is not a good idea (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36964192/11810946))

A better solution is to use the threaded interface to the network loop (see [this section of the readme](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#loop-startstop-example) and [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/examples/loop_asyncio.py)). The following is untested pseudo code to provide you with a starting point:

```py
import asyncio
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt_client

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connection returned result: "+connack_string(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic)

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    # Do something with the message
    print("Received message '" + str(message.payload) + "' on topic '"
        + message.topic + "' with QoS " + str(message.qos))

client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
client.on_connect = on_connect # Do the subscribe etc in the callback
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(broker, port)
client.loop_start() # Start network loop in separate thread

while True: # infinite loop 
    await asyncio.sleep(120) # Pause for two minutes
    print("Publishing")
    client.publish(topic, msg0)
    client.publish(topicState, msgState)
```

Another way of accomplishing this is to call [`loop`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#loop) regularly to process network events (but in this case that seems a little more complex and [comments in the code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L1090) recommend against using this on its own).